# Is there a neater way to put these hashes/arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a method from a long script that creates a hash from genetic sequences, however it is really messy and thus I was wondering whether there was a way to put it more elegantly.

Here is a sample of the script (i.e. it contains an example)...

```
def make_hash(motif)
  main_hash = Hash.new
  id = ">isotig00009_f2_3 ~: S.P. Cleavage Site: 22:23 - S.P. D-value: 0.532"
  seq = "MLKCFSIIMGLILLLEIGGGCA~IYFYRAQIQAQFQKSLTDVTITDYRENADFQDLIDALQSGLSCCGVNSYEDWDNNIYFNCSGPANNPEALWCAFLLLYTGSSKRSSQHPVRLWSSFPRTTKYFPHKDLHHWLCGYVYNVD"

  id_hash = Hash[[[:id_start, :id_end], id.split("~").map(&:strip)].transpose]
  seq_hash = Hash[[[:signalp, :seq_end], seq.split("~").map(&:strip)].transpose]

  signalp = seq_hash[:signalp] 
  new_seq_end = seq_hash[:seq_end].gsub(/#{motif}/, '<span class="motif">\0</span>')

  new_seq_hash = Hash[:signalp => signalp, :new_seq_end => new_seq_end ]

  main_hash[id_hash] = [new_seq_hash]
  return main_hash
end

motif = "VT|QAQ|F.D"
main_hash = make_hash(motif)

main_hash.each do |id_hash, seq_hash|
  puts id_hash[:id_start]
  puts id_hash[:id_end]
  puts seq_hash[0][:signalp] 
  puts seq_hash[0][:new_seq_end]
end
```

So Is there a more elegant way to write the make_hash method...

Many Thanks

Comment: We need to know what it's actually doing.

Comment: This question would be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think this simplification will work:

```
def make_hash(motif)
  id = ">isotig00009_f2_3 ~: S.P. Cleavage Site: 22:23 - S.P. D-value: 0.532"
  seq = "MLKCFSIIMGLILLLEIGGGCA~IYFYRAQIQAQFQKSLTDVTITDYRENADFQDLIDALQSGLSCCGVNSYEDWDNNIYFNCSGPANNPEALWCAFLLLYTGSSKRSSQHPVRLWSSFPRTTKYFPHKDLHHWLCGYVYNVD"

  id_hash = Hash[[[:id_start, :id_end], id.split("~").map(&:strip)].transpose]

  f, s = seq.split("~").map(&:strip)
  s.gsub!(/#{motif}/, '<span class="motif">\0</span>')

  new_seq_hash = Hash[Hash[:signalp, f], Hash[:new_seq_end, s]]

  Hash[id_hash, new_seq_hash]
end
```

If (as it appears) `id` and `seq` both have constant values, you might consider breaking them apart manually, rather than with `id.split("~").map(&:strip)`; i.e.,

```
  id1  = ">isotig00009_f2_3
  id2  = ": S.P. Cleavage Site: 22:23 - S.P. D-value: 0.532"
  seq1 = "MLKCFSIIMGLILLLEIGGGCA"
  seq2 = "IYFYRAQIQAQFQKSLTDVTITDYRENADFQDLIDALQSGLSCCGVNSYEDWDNNIYFNCSGPANNPEALWCAFLLLYTGSSKRSSQHPVRLWSSFPRTTKYFPHKDLHHWLCGYVYNVD"
```

If there were a need to make `seq2` more readable, we could use the "line continuation" character, `\` (which even works within strings) like this:

```
  seq2 = "IYFYRAQIQAQFQKSLTDVTITDYRENADFQDLIDALQSGLSCCGVNSYEDWDNNIYFNC"\
         "SGPANNPEALWCAFLLLYTGSSKRSSQHPVRLWSSFPRTTKYFPHKDLHHWLCGYVYNVD"
```

or this:

```
  seq2 = "IYFYRAQIQAQFQKSLTDVTITDYRENADFQDLIDALQSGLSCCGVNSYEDWDNNIYFNC\
SGPANNPEALWCAFLLLYTGSSKRSSQHPVRLWSSFPRTTKYFPHKDLHHWLCGYVYNVD"
```

If you preferred, you could make 'id' and 'seq' constants ('ID' and 'SEQ', say) and move them outside the method definition.  Not surprisingly, line continuation also works for constant strings.

Comment: Just a question, in the first code example you have the escaping sign ('\') when doing the gsub method. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: Ismail, whenever `` is the last character on a line, it means the line continues on the next line. I put that in to make it more readable, but my choice of location was poor.  I cleaned up the code a little and there is now no need for line continuation.  I also took the opportunity to discuss the use of line continuation within a string.